# Attach event to textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

How to attach to textbox event Mouse.PreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElementEvent.
The

```
AddHandler(Mouse.PreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElementEvent,
                new EventHandler<MouseButtonEventArgs>(HandleClickOutsideOfControl), true); contrstruction is not working.
```

I was trying to do it in textbox_loaded event.
I got the exception

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Additional information: Handler type is mismatched."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is for that a method can be called with invalid arguments. An ArgumentException may be thrown in this case. Exceptions use derived types to indicate their meaning. But this does not give them extra abilities.

Use this:

```
AddHandler(Mouse.PreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElementEvent,
            new MouseButtonEventHandler(HandleClickOutsideOfControl), true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
AddHandler(Mouse.PreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElementEvent,
            new MouseButtonEventHandler(HandleClickOutsideOfControl), true);
```

You also note that the signature of the `HandleClickOutsideOfControl` should be like this:

```
void HandleClickOutsideOfControl(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e){...}
```

Your mistake is because you thought the generic delegate `EventHandler<MouseButtonEventArgs>` is the same and can replace a `MouseButtonEventHandler`, but they are totally different delegates.